# Sound Delay With AVAudio Player

Tags: iphone, sound

I'm using the following code in my viewDidLoad to load a sound:

```
NSURL * url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:
   [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/Moto - Hit Sound.mp3",
   [[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath]]];
NSError * error;
hitSoundPlayer = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc]initWithContentsOfURL:url error:&error];
hitSoundPlayer.numberOfLoops = 0;
```

Then I'm using this in a void method to play the sound:

```
if(CGRectIntersectsRect(main.frame, enemy1.frame)){
    [hitSoundPlayer play];
}
```

This does seem to work, however the first time the sound is played there is a lot of lag and the game stops temporarily. I'm using this same method for when in an `IBAction` and it works fine, it must be the fact that it's also detecting a collision that makes the sound lag. If I want to be able to play sounds quickly and on the spot without any sort of lag am I doing the right thing? Do I want to use another method?
I'm not using any frameworks like cocos2d. If you need to see any more code just ask.

Answer (score 1):

Try calling prepareToPlay after AVAudioPlayer is initialised.

```
[hitSoundPlayer prepareToPlay];
```

Also, if AVAudioPlayer is not the first initialised it might not be using the hardware to play the audio?

Comment: +1 Because whatever else is contributing, part of this likely has to do with decoder delay since the file is an mp3, and it looks like the `prepareToPlay` message prepares the first frame of audio. Sound effects are usually stored in a format that takes little or no work to decode, or else decoded at load time and stored uncompressed in memory so they can be played instantly.